# Какие существуют игровые движки на Java?

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Ни для кого не секрет, что игры создаются на различных движках. Все зависит от того, каким языком программирования вы пользуетесь. Например, со знанием C++ для вас возможно программирование при поддержке таких движков, как CRYENGINE или Frostbite, на C# и JavaScript'е вы можете программировать в движке Unity3D.

А в каком движке нужно работать, чтобы создавать игры на Java?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

***Все движки, рассмотренные здесь, распространяются бесплатно***

### 3D Движки

---

**jMonkey Engine**.
Отличная производительность, кроссплатформенность, свой SDK+редакторы, дружелюбное сообщество (вот только англоязычное). Частые обновления и отличная поддержка со стороны разрабов самого движка не может не радовать. Есть модификация версии от 2009 года, её авторы гордо именуют свой мод отдельным движком - Ardor3D (но вот только проект загнулся, какая досада). Даже официальный сайт модификации уже не работает, а перенаравляет на личный блог разработчиков.
"Под капотом" стоит LWJGL (Light-Weight JavaGL), поддержка OpenGL v2+ и шейдеров. Плюшки - поддержка всякой лабуды типа Oculus Rift; возможна разработка Android-приложений.

Мой вывод: если готовы приступить к более-чем-любительской разработке серьёзных проектов, то jME - ваш выбор.

[Официальный сайт](http://jmonkeyengine.org/)

[Приложения на jME](http://jmonkeyengine.org/?post_type=project)

[Блог разработчика Ardor3D](http://blog.renanse.com/)

---

**Bonzai Engine**.
Великолепные утилиты для разработки, но нет как и документации, так и сообщества. Немного отойду от темы и проведу небольшое сравнение сообществ движков jME и Bonzai Engine: в одном только Твиттере у jMonkey Engine 1725 подписчиков, а у Bonzai Engine всего 12. Продолжу: кроссплатформенность (Windows/Linux/Android), OpenGL v2+. Плюшки: редакторы есть даже на Android. Также движок обещает поддержку большого количества форматов моделей.

**Апдейт**: документация внезапно [появилась](http://bonzaiengine.com/javadoc/index.html) (просто я полтора года назад изучал этот движок, но документации не было вообще). Достойных (да и просто) проектов на этом движке я пока не встречал.

Мой вывод: обёртка классная, а начинка оставляет желать лучшего.

[Официальный сайт](http://bonzaiengine.com/index.php)

Приложения на Bonzai Engine: ???

---

**jPCT**.
Врядли библиотеку размером в 300 кб можно назвать движком, но всё же это лёгкий инструмент для создания простейших приложений. Есть неофициальный редактор, куча подробной документации и довольно большое дружелюбное(!) сообщество (был случай, что на форуме мне помогал сам создатель движка). Также есть поддержка Android (версия jPCT-AE). За "плечами" движка имеется куча приложений, созданных пользователями (лично я сам залипаю в одну игрушку). Прошу учесть, что такой "движок" не даст такую великолепную картинку, как, например, jME и Bonzai Engine, но тут FPS держится выше и стабильнее. Плюшки: поддержка скелетной анимации.

Мой вывод: "дёшево и сердито".

[Официальный сайт](http://www.jpct.net/)

[Приложения на jPCT](http://www.jpct.net/projects.html)

Если кому интересно, то вот [игрушка, в которую я залипаю](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zr.music.run).

---

### 2D Движки

---

**Slick2D**.
Хороший производительный движок с открытым исходным кодом (лицензия BSD). Кроссплатформенность (Windows/Linux/Mac), поддержка OpenGL v2+. Плюшки: модуль физики jBox2D; легко делается GUI.

[Официальный сайт](http://slick.ninjacave.com/)

[Приложения на Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=2)

---

**Golden T Game Engine**.
Движок уже стар (2004), но всё же имеет право на существование. По аналогии с jPCT сгодится для простейших приложений. Поддержка OpenGL v1+. Несмотря на то, что движку уже 11й год, его форумы и поддержка всё ещё работают.

[Официальный сайт](http://www.goldenstudios.or.id/)

[Приложения на GTGE](http://www.goldenstudios.or.id/products/games/index.php)

---

**PulpCore**.
Open-source движок с неплохой производительностью. Как я понял, работает только в плагинах, но планируется сделать этот движок рабочим и на десктопах. Плюшки: тонна туториалов; движок заточен для работы с анимацией.

[Официальный "сайт" (Google Code)](https://code.google.com/p/pulpcore/)

[Несколько приложений-примеров на PulpCore](http://www.primordion.com/Xholon/pulpcore/)

Comment: @SuperCreeper Сразу следующий вопрос. А могу ли я создавать качественные игры в Android Studio?

Comment: @smily_prg, создавать игры в Android Studiо вы, конечно, можете. А вот качественные ли - зависит от ваших умений, знаний и навыков;)

Comment: @SuperCreeper Большое спасибо за развернутый и понятный ответ. Приятно было прочитать.

Answer (score 13):

Еще есть популярный опенсорс движок [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com)

На нем можно создавать игры на Windows, Linux, MacOS, Android, iOs и под браузер через WebGL.

[Игры на LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/gallery.html)

[Документация](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html)

Comment: Дополняю: товарищ @Suvitruf также делает очень понятные и интересные туториалы по libGDX для Android. [Ссылка](http://suvitruf.ru/libgdx/)

Comment: @Mashin Спасибо за данную информацию